# Java TCP: How to abort/stop the receiver from waiting for sender data after timeout

Tags: java, timeout, readline, break

I have to write java codes implementing the TCP server & TCP client with a 10% of transmission failure determined by a random number. Now in the receiver side it needs to wait for 2000 ms(2 sec.) & if no data received from the sender in this 2 sec. then it will stop waiting for data from the sender & send back a negative ACK to the sender.

```
BufferedReader inFromSender =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 2000 )
        {
            clientSentence = inFromSender.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        }
        System.out.println("Data Transmission failed");
```

But once the while loop begins & the receiver goes in to read from the sender, it never breaks.. even if the 2 sec. timeout is over. How can I abort/stop the receiver from waiting for sender data after 2 sec (timeout).

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Please give more details on what you observe. What happens after 2 secs? Which line of code is it waiting on? Trying to answer these questions will help you.

Comment: As TCP is a reliable transport the typical failure rate is so low you don't need to code for this i.e. it does re-transmissions for you.

Comment: IceMan & Peter
sorry for not replying your queries. This was a mere homework assignment where I was told to **force a 2secs timeout** in the receiving end. aymeric 's idea did the job for me though. Thanks for your concerns. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go would be to have a `Thread` that would close the socket when the timeout is reached. This would make the `read(...)` call fail (probably an `IOException`) and therefore you would go out from the loop.

Example:

```
final Socket connectionSocket = new Socket("...", 8888); // To be changed
BufferedReader inFromSender = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
Thread t = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
      try {
          Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait 2 s
          connectionSocket.close();
          System.out.println("Data Transmission failed");
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {
         // Handle exception
      }
   }
};
t.start();
while((clientSentence = inFromSender.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
}
```